# Every Borel set is the union of an increasing sequence of Bounded Borel sets?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, compactness

I am currently working with the book by Halmos, and i can't quite get past this one.
It states that:

"Every Borel set can be written as an increasing sequence of Bounded Borel sets"

In this case $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, the Borel sets $B_c$ is the $\sigma$-ring generated by the compact sets, and a bounded set is any set contained in a compact set.

I know that every Borel set is $\sigma$-bounded, that is for every $A \in B_c$ there is a countable collection of compact sets $\{K_n\} \in X$ such that $A \subseteq \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} K_n$. If i knew that $A$ was $\sigma$-compact ($A = \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} K_n$), then it follows since each $A_j = K_1 \cup ... \cup K_j$ is compact and trivially bounded, $\{A_j\}$ is an increasing sequence and $A = \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} A_j$.

Is this the way to show it(and how do i know that $A$ is $\sigma$-compact?) or is there a much simpler explanation?

Best regards, Soren.

Comment: No, not every Borel set is sigma-compact.  Perhaps you need to show $A \cap K_n$ is Borel, for each $n$ ??

Comment: Hint: remember that compact sets are closed in Hausdorff spaces, and the Borel ring is closed under at-most-countable intersections.